# FirewallD trusted zone and blocking ip

Tags: centos, security, redhat, linux-networking, firewalld

So I'll try to not get in to the details, but I'm having to use the "trusted" zone in firewalld (dev's keep complaining its the firewalld blocking their software, and want me to turn the firewalls off).

I would like to block a single IP (the network gateway) in the trusted zone.

I have done:
added the network to the trusted zone

## add the subnet to trusted zone

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --permanent --add-source=192.168.0.0/16
```

## block the ip

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address=192.168.0.1 reject'
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address=192.168.0.1 drop'
```

## block everywhere because still working

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address=192.168.0.1 reject'
sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address=192.168.0.1 drop'
```

## make the default zone drop

```
sudo firewall-cmd --set-default=drop
```

## reload

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

## and make sure its all there

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
```

I'm guessing the order in which the iptables are the problem. Is there another way ? or am I missing something. I've even tried adding source and dest to the block.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you source address is the gateway? For example, depending on your setup a host that is not your gateway connecting to you host would have its own IP address as the source even though it comes through your gateway. You can also try running tcpdump and monitor what comes in when you test the configurations you are expecting to block to see the true source address. Good luck

Comment: thanks for the input! Yes it was very confusing... running tcpdump/wireshark is helpful
I ended up using firewalld "direct" rules. And talking bossman into going about this a different way.